# How to check fabric block size (in bytes)

Tags: size, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I used Hyperledger Explorer, but i haven't any information of block size.
I need to understand how many transactions saturate 1GB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the docker files provided by Hyperledger, a mounted directory called prod is created when you run the network. This directory contains a directory for each peer. Inside a given peers directory there is `chains/chains/<nameOfChannel>`- in there are the block files. You can use traditional linux methods to get size of those files.

Comment: I found blockfile_000000 in /var/lib/docker/volumes/<peer's volume>/_data/ledgersData/chains/chains/channel

Thanks!!!

Comment: @EugenioBalì no problem! Could you select my answer and maybe an upvote so I can get some reputation points?:) thx